# Finding another series for a given series.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

For each sequence $$a_n$$ find a number `r` such that $$\frac{a_n}{r^n}$$
has a finite non-zero limit.
(This is of use, because by the limit comparison test the series $$\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$$ and $$\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty r^n $$both converge or both diverge.)
A. $$a_n = (5 + 5 ^ n)^{- 4}$$
r =

Answer (score 0):

This is impossible. There are many sequences $a_n$ for which there is no such a $r$.

Moreover, your assertion that ${a_n}$ and $r^{n}$ converge or not simultaneously is only true if the sequence ${a_n}$ has positive terms.

On the other hand, $\sum (5 + 5^n)^{-4}$ converges because $0\leq (5 + 5^n)^{-4} \leq (5^{-4})^{n}$.

Comment: Can you please show your steps of how you came to the conclusion of $$0\leq (5 + 5^n)^{-4} \leq (5^{-4})^{n}$$
@RobertFuster

Comment: It is a trivial exercise!

Comment: That's the reason I asked the question in the first place.If I knew I wouldn't be asking for help.